# 404 error when accessing Django STATIC resources inside Docker image

Tags: django, docker, static

This is the Dockerfile for my Django project:

```
FROM python:3.10.5-alpine

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODEBYDEFAULT=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN adduser --disabled-password appuser

USER appuser

WORKDIR /home/appuser/app

COPY requirements.txt .

USER root

RUN python -m pip install --no-cache-dir --disable-pip-version-check --requirement requirements.txt

USER appuser

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT [ "./entrypoint.sh" ]
```

And Django settings regarding static assets:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/'
```

And `entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
gunicorn project.wsgi:application --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 --workers=4 --timeout=300 --log-level=debug --log-file=-

exec "$@"
```

When I start the container I shell into it and see that `static` folder **is created and populated** with admin staff.

However browsing `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin` brings up the admin login page **without** any CSS and I get lots of `404` errors in the developer console.

I also changed `STATIC_ROOT` to `/home/appuser/app/static/` and got the same.

Please assist.

Comment: Are you using nginx as your server?

Comment: I've tried with Nginx too, as well as Gunicorn and also the development server of Django (```python manage.py runserver```).  The issue is with Docker. Outside Docker I have no issue.

Comment: If you're using django dev server you shouldn't get any errors with it. But if you proxy your app through Nginx you need also create a location for statifiles and also mount a volume to Nginx container with static files.

I'm using docker-compose. Here's an example:

smarts-nginx:
    image: nginx:stable
    restart: "on-failure"
    volumes:
      - static_files:/static


And in my nginx config:
server {
    location /static {
     alias /static;
    }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check for the permissions of the created static folder?

I had to manually change the permissions of the folders.

you could try with following Dockerfile for nginx:

```
FROM nginx:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y procps
RUN mkdir -p /home/app/staticfiles
RUN chmod -R 755 /home/app/staticfiles
```

Comment: While your code is not the solution it was indeed permission issue so thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using this config.

Django:

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
```

Dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir -p /home/appuser/app/staticfiles
```

Nginx.conf

```
location /static/ {
    alias /home/appuser/app/staticfiles/;
}
```

docker-compouse.yml something like:

```
web:
container_name: test_table_django
build: .
command:
  sh -c "python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear &&
    python manage.py migrate &&
    gunicorn --workers=4 --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 test_table.wsgi:application"
volumes:
    - .:/home/appuser/app
    - static_volume:/home/appuser/app/staticfiles/
env_file:
  - .env.prod
expose:
  - 8000
depends_on:
  - db
restart: always

nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: test_table_nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/appuser/app/staticfiles/
```

Answer (score 0):

The static URL should start with `/`.
You can also check the logs to see where it is trying to reach to.

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'static')
```